# Aligning horizontal text in <p> to an angled <div>

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I'm trying to created a staircase effect with text on my page. I've wrapped a `<p>` element inside a `<section>.` The section has the following styling:

```
section{
    transform:rotate(-37.6deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-37.6deg); 
    -moz-transform:rotate(-37.6deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-37.6deg); 
    width: 200px;       
}
```

I'd like the text in my `<p>` to be constrained to the rotated box I've created, and then be able to rotate the text so that each line is horizontal, stepping down along the line of the `<section>` box.

[This](http://webmaster.senecacollege.ca/daharbri/www102/www102_assignment2/css/home.html) is the link to the page, so you can have a better idea what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: It seems to be to be able to do this, the <p> would need to be an inline element, making each line editable for rotation on it's own axis. The problem is, when the paragraph has been set to inline, the rotation command no longer works, correct?

Comment: I don't think posible to do it for a multi-line <p>, at least the way that you are trying. You can do it setting the <p> to display block, and then making every p hold only 1 line of text (not very practical)

Comment: I had this working yesterday. Four hrs in now, and I can't replicate the effect. Is it possible that the browsers on my computer were accepting transform: rotate commands for an inline element?

Comment: It works for me with inline-block and inline-table, but the rotation is done for the full p, not for every line in the p

Comment: Not related to this question, but note that the unprefixed version of the property should come last, so that it wins out in the cascade when it is supported. Otherwise the prefixed version will overwrite it. It would also be good to add a -o- prefix for Opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve your goal with this approach because *CSS Transformations* are rendered by GPU **after** DOM rendering, and for this reason (for example) transformed elements don't affect others elements positions and sizes.

To achieve your goal you should use a jQuery solution, like this "http://www.csstextwrap.com/"